# How to log all information going out and coming into CURL?

Tags: php, curl

Client1 send requests to Server1 and get response through php curl. I only have access to Client1 source-code and I need to log all the requests and responses that are going out and coming into Client1 and save it as a txt file.

The reason of doing this is to replace Server1 by a new server. The Client1 source-code is very complicated so I decided to log all the requests and responses so that I can reverse engineer the Server1.

There are some answers to similar questions using Linux commands (e.g using --verbose and --trace-ascii) or using WireShark but I couldn't understand them also I have to implement it inside my code and not using commands. How to do that?

The below is the curl function:

```
    private function fba8eb($ia61712c)
{
    if (empty($this->v9e19674cb))
        return false;
    $this->query = $ia61712c;
    preg_match('/action=(.*?)&/', $ia61712c, $i43da24755ffd);
    $i87f2ea = $i43da24755ffd[1];
    switch ($this->v488f1ce) {
        case 'no-ssl':
        case 'ssl':
            fwrite($this->v9e19674cb, "POST " . $this->v7d5fd . " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
            fwrite($this->v9e19674cb, "User-Agent: Smsmidlet-api/1.0 (" . $this->v488f1ce . "; " . $this->v9f1e7fea . "; " . $this->v9f1e7fea_version . "; call: $i87f2ea)\r\n");
            fwrite($this->v9e19674cb, "Host: " . $this->v45213b . "\r\n");
            fwrite($this->v9e19674cb, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8\r\n");
            fwrite($this->v9e19674cb, "Content-length: " . strlen($ia61712c) . "\r\n");
            fwrite($this->v9e19674cb, "\r\n" . $ia61712c . "\r\n");
            $i3bd625bb = '';
            while (!feof($this->v9e19674cb)) {
                @$i3bd625bb .= fgets($this->v9e19674cb, 2048);
            }
            $ie4a1f55ce = fclose($this->v9e19674cb);
            list($ie3dffdbcc, $this->data) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $i3bd625bb, 2);
            return $this->data;
            break;
        case 'curl':
        case 'curl-ssl':
            if (get_resource_type($this->v9e19674cb) == 'curl') {
                @curl_setopt($this->v9e19674cb, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                @curl_setopt($this->v9e19674cb, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ia61712c);
                @curl_setopt($this->v9e19674cb, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                @curl_setopt($this->v9e19674cb, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                @curl_setopt($this->v9e19674cb, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                @curl_setopt($this->v9e19674cb, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                @curl_setopt($this->v9e19674cb, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Seridlet-api/1.0 (' . $this->v488f1ce . '; ' . $this->v9f1e7fea . '; ' . $this->v9f1e7fea_version . "; call: $i87f2ea )");
                @$i3bd625bb = curl_exec($this->v9e19674cb);
                $i3bd625bb = html_entity_decode($i3bd625bb);
                curl_close($this->v9e19674cb);
                return $this->data = $i3bd625bb;
            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Interesting Variable and Function names.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could get what you need by just making a logging function and doing

```
private function fba8eb($ia61712c)
{
    {
        ob_start();
        var_dump($_GET,$_POST,$_COOKIE,$this,$ia61712c);
        $debugstr=ob_get_clean();
        log_debug_info($debugstr);
        unset($deugstr);
    }
if (empty($this->v9e19674cb))
```

?

another thing that comes to mind, is CURLOPT_VERBOSE and CURLOPT_STDERR.

is the code already using CURLOPT_STDERR? if not, you could make a tmpfile(), give it to CURLOPT_STDERR, enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE, and log the contents of it when curl is done (notice that you'll need to give stream_get_meta_data($tmpfile)['uri'] to CURLOPT_STDERR, not the file handle itself, but the path, which stream_get_meta_data gives you.)

Comment: You meant something like this:
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);`
`$fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/log.txt', 'w'); `

Comment: more like `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR,dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt'); ` - PS, you only need `dirname(__FILE__)` if you're running PHP 5.2 or older. as of PHP 5.3+, just use `__DIR__` . however note, there's some concurrency problems if you have many curl instances writing to stderr of the same logfile at the same time, but if not, i guess its fine (different curls could start writing in the middle of each others)

Comment: I tried it and it returns some information but not the parameters and their values. The output is:
`*   Trying 45.145.143.19...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to Seridlet.com (45.145.143.19) port 80 (#0)
&gt; POST /api/api.php HTTP/1.1
Host: Seridlet.com
User-Agent: Seridlet-api/1.0 (curl; Magento; 1.9.2.4; call: sendinfo )
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 255
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 255 out of 255 bytes
&lt; HTTP/1.1 200 OK
&lt; Date: Fri, 23 Jun 2017 12:19:20 GMT
&lt; Server: Apache/2
&lt; Vary: Accept-Encoding
...`